# vue.jsのv-bind:style構文で条件分技をしたい

Tags: javascript, vue.js

以下のソースで`map.banned`がfalseの場合に`cursor:pointer`を追加してtrueの場合に消したかったのですが、どちらの場合でも`cursor:pointer`がついてしまいます。

上の`v-bind:class`では条件式を正しく評価できています。

`v-bind:style`では`v-bind:class`のような条件式をつかえないのでしょうか、それとも他に方法があるのでしょうか。

**html**

```
<ul class="list-group" id="map-list">
  <li class="list-group-item" v-for="(map, index) in maps" v-on:click="listClicked" 
    v-bind:value="index" 
    v-bind:class="[map.banned ? disabled : '']"
    v-bind:style="[map.benned ? '': pointer]"
  >{% map.name %}</li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript(vue.jsの初期化部分抜粋)**

```
 data: {
   maps: maps,
   disabled: "disabled",
   pointer: {
     cursor: "pointer"
   }          
 },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

単純なTypoではないですか？v-bind:styleのmap.**benned**をmap.bannedになおすと正しく動いているように見えます。

```js
const maps = [{
  banned: true,
  name: "test1",
},{
  banned: false,
  name: "test2",
}];
new Vue({
  el: "#map-list",
  data: {
   maps: maps,
   disabled: "disabled",
   pointer: {
     cursor: "pointer"
   }
 },
});
```

```css
.disabled {
  color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.8/vue.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list-group" id="map-list">
  <li class="list-group-item" v-for="(map, index) in maps" 
    :value="index" 
    :class="[map.banned ? disabled : '']"
    :style="[map.banned ? '' : pointer]"
  >{{ map.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Typoでした。ご指摘ありがとうございます